# How to configure Odoo memory usage for multi-instance?

Tags: memory, configuration, crash, limit, odoo

We have 3 instances in a single server with different ports `(8069, 8040, 8060)` and different Odoo version (10, 11, 12). Server specifications are 4 CPU and 8 GB RAM.

We have an issue with Odoo 12 only, he crash sometimes. In the log, we have these lines : `"virtual real time limit (181/120s) reached."`

It's a server test, we are only 3 or 4 users on it with 5 or 6 databases, no used on same time.

We tried many manipulations found on the web, like change memory limit, change number of workers... Nothing change. Moreover, when we activate workers, we have another issue : `"raise Exception("Exception: bus.Bus unavailable")"`

We delete configuration line about longpolling port too, nothing change.

[Odoo Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1S0n.png)
[Nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmZsa.png)

We would like to delete all wrongs logs with an optimize configuration for Odo multi-instance.